# is getHibernateTemplate().flush() release data base connection

Tags: spring, hibernate

Please let me to know is `getHibernateTemplate().flush()` release data base connection after commit. If not what is the procedure to release data base connection.

I cant use hibernate transaction manager to resolve this.

Comment: Why aren't you able to use the `HibernateTransactionManager` when using spring you should use this to manage your transactions.

Answer (score 2):

calling `flush` be it on the `HibernateTemplate` or `Session` doesn't release anything it will only flush the pending sql statements to the database.

A connection will be releases as soon as the `Session` is closed, when this is depends on your setup.

Note: `HibernateTemplate` should be considered deprecated as of Hibernate 3.0.1 (this is when contextual sessions where introduced) and you should favor plain `Session` usage of the `HibernateTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

getHibernateTemplate().flush() will not release DB connection after commit. flush() will just synchronize your persistence context state with DB by firing update queries.

Connection will be closed when the hibernate session ends. However you can start a new transaction once the current one finishes.

Additional reference: [function of getHibernateTemplate().flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766654/function-of-gethibernatetemplate-flush?rq=1)